# Как ограничить длину списка у .selectmenu JQuery UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Есть выпадающее меню сделанное благодаря стилизации тега `select` с классом `meal` через `.selectmenu`, в списке очень много элементов и при открытии они все "вываливаются" наружу. Как ограничить длину выпадающего списка, например до 6 значений, а сбоку появлялась скролл линия?

Comment: Нашёл решение, дело в том, что JQuery UI устанавливает исходному select стиль display:  none; и вместо него впихивает спаны и списки, надо было в DOM найти элемент отвечающий за список и определить его класс, после чего осталось самоё легкое, задать этому классу max-height: n px; и overflow: auto (За стили спасибо @keker123)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл решение, дело в том, что JQuery UI устанавливает исходному `select` стиль `display: none;` и вместо него впихивает спаны и списки, надо было в *DOM* найти элемент отвечающий за список и определить его класс, после чего осталось самоё легкое, задать этому классу `max-height: n px;` и `overflow: auto` (За стили спасибо @keker123)